# Cursor not disappearing despite the textbox becoming invisible

Tags: jquery, html, css

While creating a web page where I dynamically hide elements and move pictures over them I have stumbled over a problem I can't explain at all. When I try the same thing in jsfiddle it works, but locally I get a problem.

The problem is that when a textbox in which the cursor is located becomes invisible.....the cursor is still displayed despite the textbox disappeared and an image being put onto that location.

I've created a jsfiddle as this page here doesnt like the html commands somehow oO:
http://jsfiddle.net/x1af53sy/

What I'm doing in essence is: I have a text field which becomes invisible while a picture is then (with position fixed) put onto the former location of the text field. The becoming invisible is done with the following code:

```
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
z-index: 0;
```

In jsfiddle it works, but locally I still get the cursor displayed if the focus had been on the text field. I didn't find anything in the css that would explain this. So my question is what could be the cause of this unexpected behaviour (I even deactivated every other Css I found to no avail)?

As a bit of additional infos:

- The whole application is an aspx.net application
- I'm using jQuery 1.11.2
- The original textbox is a telerik radtext box (but I also tried replacing it with a normal aspx textbox but still got the same result)

As it was mentioned in a few answers:
I already tried using display: none  or even cursor: none. The blinking cursor is still being displayed despite this (the textbox itself disappears as expected and wanted, but the cursor symbols still prevails)

If I use "text-indent: -9999em;" while the textfield is invisible it works by the text not being displayed but as that is a workaround I'm still interested in what could cause this phenomenon (and how to really battle it).

Comment: The cursor remains visible on the fiddle for me as well. Where/when is the cursor supposed to disappear?

Comment: the cursor is supposed to disappear alongside the input field as soon as you leave the big border